# Running an infinite loop in multiple command prompts using batch script

Tags: batch-file

I'm trying to write an batch script to run an infinite loop in 10 different command prompts ,but that doesn't seem to work fine .It opens the command prompts and disappears ,i have posted the script below please let me know where exactly is the problem.

```
 for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (

start cmd /c ":up echo loop && goto up"

 )
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think two issues block the functionality (you want).

1. By using echo all the remaining of the line will be printed (even if you get the loop working).
2. Working with labels requires the use of script file(s). You can't use labels in the console. (I mean interactively: try it, enter a `:label`, enter some other lines and than enter goto `label`. Then you won't get into a loop!)

When I use for *caller.cmd*:

```
for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (
    start cmd /c test.cmd
)
```

and for *test.cmd*:

```
:up 
echo loop 
goto up
```

it works (at least for me ...)

Even when I use for *test.cmd*:

```
:up 
echo loop && goto up
```

it works. But than each console will show `loop && goto up` in stead of `loop`!

While I was writing this down, Martyn had already given a likewise answer. Maybe that's convincing enough for you.

Answer (score 4):

```
for /l %%a in (0) do start "%~f0"
```

Comment: This i know , but i want multiple instances of it opened once

Comment: This was about to crash my system , but it opens many command prompts :)

Comment: The only infinite loop working frome console, not only from bat-file.

Answer (score 2):

I would do this in 2 different batch files.

1 file is the start up, and opens the 2nd batch 10 times.

in the 2nd batch you would have whatever work you want done.

Batch 1 (start.bat):

```
 for /l %%x in (1, 1, 10) do (

 start "loop" loop.bat

 )

 pause
```

Batch 2(loop.bat):

```
REM Whatever work you want to be looping, for testing I have left it as a pause.
pause
```

then just run start.bat and you will see it open 10 new command windows all with the pause command.

Martyn

Answer (score 2):

Your batch is not working because labels require new line before commands, and you don't even have a `&` after `:up`. I would make it this way:

```
If Not %1.==. GoTo :Up
For /L %%i In (1,1,10) Do Start "%~nx0 %%i" Cmd /C %0 %%i
GoTo :EOF

:Up
Echo %1
GoTo :Up
```